# Post WebApi Method With Parameter C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I would like to just post Webapi method in asp.net mvc the post action method looks like

```
  [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/agency/Dashboard")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Index(getCookiesModel cookies)
    {
     //code here
    }
```

and I am sending post request like this

```
  string result = webClient.DownloadString("http://localhost:11668/api/agency/dashboard?cookies=" + cookies);
```

and the getCookiesModel

```
 public class getCookiesModel
{
    public string userToken { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public long userId { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string usercode { get; set; }
}
```

But this return 404 page not found.
Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: `DownloadString` is a GET request and since the action is expecting a POST, you can see where that may be a problem.

Comment: how to solve please.

Comment: Uh...change from Post to Get?

Comment: @DumpsterDiver: Remove the `[HttpPost]` annotation so the action can be used from a GET request.

Answer (score 2):

`DownloadString` is a GET request and since the action is expecting a POST, you can see where that may be a problem.

Consider using `HttpClient` to post the request. If sending the payload in the body then there is no need for the query string, so you also need to update the client calling URL.

```
var client = new HttpCient { 
    BaseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:11668/")
};

var model = new getCookiesModel() {
    //...populate properties.
};
var url = "api/agency/dashboard";
//send POST request
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);
//read the content of the response as a string
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The web API should follow the following syntax

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/agency/Dashboard")]
public IHttpActionResult Index([FromBody]getCookiesModel cookies) {
    //code here...
    return Ok();
}
```